# Propagate SOAPFault with simple Camel proxy

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-camel

I'm trying to create a simple WS proxy using Switchyard 1.1 with Camel:

--> PromotedService --> Camel --> ProxifiedService

With the current configuration I'm able to send and recieve messages without any problem. 
However, when the ProxifiedService throws a SoapFault it is not propagated to the caller of the PromotedService.

What can I do to ensure the the PromotedServiceCaller receives the SOAPFault as reponse?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
onException(Exception.class)  
       .process(  
          new Processor() {  
             public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {           
                SoapFault fault = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, SoapFault.class);
                System.out.println("Fault: " +  fault); // --> This returns NULL

                Exception excep = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
                System.out.println("excep: " +  excep);
                System.out.println("excep message: " + excep.getMessage());
                System.out.println("excep cause: " +  excep.getCause());

                SoapFault SOAP_FAULT = new SoapFault(excep.getMessage(), SoapFault.FAULT_CODE_CLIENT);
                Element detail = SOAP_FAULT.getOrCreateDetail();
                Document doc = detail.getOwnerDocument();
                Text tn = doc.createTextNode("this is a test");
                detail.appendChild(tn);

                exchange.getOut().setFault(true);
                exchange.getOut().setBody(SOAP_FAULT);

                exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ERRORHANDLER_HANDLED, false); 
                exchange.removeProperty("CamelExceptionCaught");  
             }  
          })  
       .handled(true)  
       .end();

        from("switchyard://PromotedService") 
            .process(myProc) // --> I just add some headers here to the original request. 
            .handleFault()   
            .to("switchyard://ProxifiedService").end();
```

This is the SOAPFault generated by the ProxifiedService:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ser="http://service.admin.ws.my.company/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
 </soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
   <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Missing valid token.</faultstring>
   </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
```

And this the message the caller is really receiving:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
       <soap:Fault>
          <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
          <faultstring>org.switchyard.HandlerException: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource@663dcb96</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

onException()  only takes Throwable. In your code the argument is SoapFault which is not  Throwable.

This will work

```
onException(SOAPException.class)
```

Comment: I tried with SOAPException, but the method is still not executed. However, if I use "onException(Exception.class)" it is executed, but I don't know how redirect the original SOAPFault to the caller.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the stacktrace and the soapfault message that should be propagated to the original caller.

Comment: cxfEndPoint interceptors treats SOAPMessage and SOAPFault same way so just construct the SOAPFault end send in body of response. Please refer to the link http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html#CXF-HowtothrowaSOAPFaultfromCamel

Comment: Thank you! I was able to throw a custom fault. However, I'm trying to obtain the original fault message thrown by the ProxifiedService, but the exception text I obtain is the string "javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource@136bd" instead of "Missing valid token."
I update the question with the code I'm using now in the process method. Why do I get that strange message about the DOM?
Thank you again for your help.